# Delete row of the table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sample code as follows :

```
<table id='emailTable'>
<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a ....>delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a ....>delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Here, I want to delete the row onclick of delete link with the next row.

Have tried with 'parentNode' and removechild with currentNode but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can attach an event listener to `a` for click event and use `$(this).parents('tr')` inside event handler to access parent row. something like this:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='emailTable'>
<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a href="">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a href="">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id='tablecontent'>
<td>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: can we use javascript instead of jquery

Comment: @Prafull we can do it using javascript, but it will be more code than this, can't you use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go table row removal using JavaScript:

```
// get all rows
var rows = document
  .querySelectorAll("#emailTable tr#tablecontent");
// create a find parent function
// since JavaScript do not have $(elem).parent("tr")
// which automatically search a parent or parent of parents that is a <tr>
var findParent = function (node, tagName)
{
   var recursiveSearch = function(node, tagName)
   {
      // you can change the condition as you see fit.
      return node.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName.toLowerCase() ? node.parentNode : recursiveSearch(node.parentNode, tagName);
   };

   // do a recursive search based from passed node if it matches with a given tag name.
   return recursiveSearch(node, tagName);
};

// loop through each row
rows.forEach(function (item)
{
   // find the delete element
   var deleteElem = item.querySelector("td a.delete");

   // if there is an delete element
   if (deleteElem)
   {
       // add event listener
       deleteElem.addEventListener("click", function ()
       {
          // find parent element that is a <tr>
          var row = findParent(this, "tr");
          // remove the row
          row.remove();
       });
   }
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L20hpwse/)

hope that helps